# Data Studio Time Series Chart Last 6 Month based on Date Filter EndDate

Tags: looker-studio

Can I have a time series chart to display the last 6 months QTY sold? as the report filter is monthly based.

ex. Users can choose 2021/10/01 - 2021/10/31 to view the report and there is a chart to display the last 6 months QTY sold. In this case, the time series chart will display 2021/05/01 to 2021/10/31.

If users can choose 2021/06/01 - 2021/6/30 to view the report and there is a chart to display the last 6 months QTY sold. In this case, the time series chart will display 2021/01/01 to 2021/06/30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through my advanced knowledge of the platform, I am not aware of the possibility of obtaining the mentioned result.

It is not possible to use the date filter control element and the respective date range as an input variable to define the period dimension used in the temporal graph.

You will probably have to look for an alternative solution that doesn't match the proposed objective. Using a fixed period of the last 6 months, without the possibility of dynamic variation through the date control element. Or, use two date filter control elements, one for the time graph only. Solutions far from ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved, I created another data source for 6 months of sales.